# RULES : How to redirect user to a page after login unless they're using the one-time-login-url?

Tags: 7, rules

I created a rule to redirect users to the front page after they login.
It works fine

The problem is when a user uses the link received on his email to choose a new password, or after clicking on the link to validate their signup, they're also forced redirected to the front page instead of heading to their user page to choose a password (in the case of a forgotten password) or finish their profile setup (after clicking on the link to validate their registration)

Any ideas on how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

**1st method:**

I believe there is a module called [**Login toboggan**](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) which will allow you to do exactly what you want.

**From the module page:**

> The LoginToboggan module offers several modifications of the Drupal
>   login system in an external module by offering the following features
>   and usability improvements:
>
> Allow users to login using either their username OR their e-mail
>   address.
>
> Allow users to login immediately.
>
> Provide a login form on Access Denied pages for non-logged-in
>   (anonymous) users.
>
> The other brings the user to a separate page, but returns the user to
>   their original page upon login.
>
> Optionally redirect the user to a specific page when using the
>   'immediate login' feature.
>
> Optionally redirect the user to a specific page upon validation of
>   their e-mail address.
>
> Optionally display a user message indicating a successful login. ...

**2nd method:**
I believe when someone **request a password**, the format of the link will be similar to this one:

https://www.drupal.org/user/reset/...

If so, you can create a rule to redirect the user upon login to a specific page. However, add **one condition** which will be:

**Data comparison**: the link should not contain the word **reset**

Hope it helps,